# Rendering component above background image with overlay

Tags: android, css, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

My problem is I can't make components to be displayed above background images.

I've read about layout properties and other related SO questions but can't seem to make it work on my project although in my understanding implementation below is correct:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

let styles = StyleSheet.create({

  backgroundImage: {
    top: -150,
    left: -275
  },

  dimOverlay: {
    flex: 1,
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },

  loginForm: {
  }
});

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput autoCorrect={false} defaultValue='asdf'/>
        <TextInput autoCorrect={false} />
      </View>
    )
  }

}

class Background extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Image source={require('./img/login_screen.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          <View style={styles.dimOverlay} />
        </Image>
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Background>
        <LoginForm/>
      </Background>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => LoginScreen);
```

I imagine there must be something fixed up with css properties, because otherwise its usually enough to display one property within enough to make the first one be seen above the second one.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

let styles = StyleSheet.create({

  backgroundImage: {
    top: -150,
    left: -275
  },

  dimOverlay: {
    flex: 1,
    opacity: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },

  loginForm: {
  }
});

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <TextInput autoCorrect={false} defaultValue='asdf' style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}/>
        <TextInput autoCorrect={false} defaultValue='ghjk' style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }

}

class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={require('./img/login_screen.jpg')} >
        <View style={styles.dimOverlay}>
        <LoginForm/>
        </View>
      </Image>


    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => LoginScreen);
```